# How do you search within a <span> tag for a specific "class=id" type attribute with Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page with BeautifulSoup which has the general format of the following:

```
<span class="ID1"> TEXT </span>
<span class="ID2"> TEXT2 </span>
```

These are all stored in a `<div>`, so my general code template looks like this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    print tag.find('span')
```

This pulls up all `<span>` tags in the `div`, but I can't figure out how to search inside of the `<span>s`. I've tried things like `tag.find('class')`, and `.find('ID')`, but no luck.

I can manually find the thing I'm looking for by getting this string representation of the object and then testing whether or not it has the ID I'm looking for, but that seems like a band-aid approach. I'm sure there's something that I'm just not seeing.

Note: I've also tried passing in a regex of the ID to the `find` function ala:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    print tag.find(re.compile('id2'))
```

Still no luck unfortunately.

So, how do I search for a specific class value?

## *EDIT [Solved]

---

I figured out how to do it via BeautifulSoup's built in `find` function without manually checking its dictionary structure.

To use the `find` function to pick out a specific `class=value` within an html tag, pass in the general tag name that you want to find as the first parameter (in my case, it was part of a '' tag). As the second argument, pass in a dictionary with the specific `'class' : 'value'` you want to find.

For example, if the HTML I want to scrape looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="ID1"> TEXT </span>
    <other HTML junk> 
    <span class="ID2"> TEXT2 </span>
</div>
```

I can use an statement like the one below.

```
for tag_elm in soup.find_all('div'):
    print tag_elm.find('span', {'class' : 'ID2'})
```

Tada!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
for tag in soup.findAll('span'):
    if tag.has_key('class'):
        if tag['class'] == 'ID2':
            # do stuff
```

Tested this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<span class="ID1"> TEXT </span>
<span class="ID2"> TEXT2 </span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

for tag in soup.findAll('span'):
    if tag.has_key('class'):
        if tag['class'] == 'ID2':
            print tag.string
            break
```

Gives the following output:

```
TEXT2
```