# Extract Number of Followers from Twitter using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automate the process of obtaining the number of followers different twitter accounts using the page source.

I have the following code for one account

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username='justinbieber'
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    if tag.has_key('class'):
        if tag['class'] == 'ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav u-textUserColor':
            if tag['href'] == '/justinbieber/followers':
                print tag.title
                break
```

I am not sure where did I went wrong. I understand that we can use Twitter API to obtain the number of followers. However, I wish to try to obtain it through this method as well to try it out. Any suggestions?

I've modified the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943087/how-do-you-search-within-a-span-tag-for-a-specific-class-id-type-attribute-w)

Comment: When I checked this code, the `if tag['class'] == 'ProfileNav ...'` never evaluated to `True`.  This suggests that no tags have a class that matches the description you gave.

Comment: Hi @jason thank you for your reply. However it seemed to show me the same string/keyword for the class tag for across all accounts.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225803/beautifulsoup-scraping-different-data-sets-having-same-set-of-attributes-in-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd be passing the class name as an argument to the `find()` function instead of `find_all()` and I'd first look for the `<li>` element that contains the anchor you're loooking for. It'd look something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username='justinbieber'
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
title = f.find('a')['title']
print title
# 81,346,708 Followers

num_followers = int(title.split(' ')[0].replace(',',''))
print num_followers
# 81346708
```

PS `findAll()` was [renamed to `find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) in bs4

Comment: hi @wilbur, thank you! Just a question, for the 'li' tag: <li class="ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers"> why did you not include "ProfileNav-item ProfileNav" as well? :) Just asking!

Comment: The way BeautifulSoup searches using classes is a little wonky. If, for example, you tried the following command, `soup.find('li', class_='ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers')` it would work just the same as the command I used. However, if you tried to execute this command, `soup.find('li', class_='ProfileNav-item--followers ProfileNav-item')`, you would get a `None` object back because the order of the classes is wrong. To avoid any of this confusion, I just searched for the class name that was unique to the `<li>` I wanted.